# Is there a way to add 480p and 240p layers to Content Adaptive Multiple Bitrate MP4 preset in azure media services

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Services for video streaming but have a problem can't solve.

Is there a way to add the 480p and 240p layer to Content Adaptive Multiple Bitrate MP4 preset?

I want to azure encoder decide my video bitrate but customize video layers.

Comment: Thanks for also reaching out to us directly - please respond with the details requested, and we'll follow up.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion, we confirmed that the current implementation of the Content Adaptive Multiple Bitrate MP4 preset does not permit further customization of the resolutions.